# Appending 2 matrices

Tags: j

```
   ]v=: 1 2;3 4;0 5;2 1 
┌───┬───┬───┬───┐
│1 2│3 4│0 5│2 1│
└───┴───┴───┴───┘
   ]d=: 1 0.5 1 0.25;0.5 1 0.75 0.25;1 0.75 1 0;0.75 0.25 0 1
┌────────────┬───────────────┬──────────┬─────────────┐
│1 0.5 1 0.25│0.5 1 0.75 0.25│1 0.75 1 0│0.75 0.25 0 1│
└────────────┴───────────────┴──────────┴─────────────┘
   force_constant=: monad def '(v ((y{>"0 v);])@{~ ] i.4) ,"1 0 <"0>(y{d)'
   force_constant 0
┌───┬───┬────┐
│1 2│1 2│1   │
├───┼───┼────┤
│1 2│3 4│0.5 │
├───┼───┼────┤
│1 2│0 5│1   │
├───┼───┼────┤
│1 2│2 1│0.25│
└───┴───┴────┘
   diff=: monad def '(v ((y{>"0 v);])@{~ ] i.4)'
   direction_vector=: monad def '<"1(-/"2(>diff y))'
   direction_vector 0
┌───┬─────┬────┬────┐
│0 0│_2 _2│1 _3│_1 1│
└───┴─────┴────┴────┘
```

Then, I want to append `direction_vector 0` to `force_constant 0` which should look like:

```
┌───┬───┬────┐─────┐
│1 2│1 2│1   │0 0  │
├───┼───┼────┼─────┤
│1 2│3 4│0.5 │_2 _2│
├───┼───┼────┼─────┤
│1 2│0 5│1   │1 _3 │
├───┼───┼────┼─────┤
│1 2│2 1│0.25│_1 1 │
└───┴───┴────┴─────┘
```

I tried to append those two matrices several times, but it gives me weird matrices.

Could anyone help me out? Thank you

Comment: Why don't you show us the code? It would be more useful than giving you the right answer.

Comment: Note that the verbs can be considerably simplified. For example: 
`diff=: monad def '(y{v) ,. v'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the dyadic verb Stitch `.,` to put together the items of force_constant with the items of direction_vector. From the J dictionary http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d321.htm

```
   (force_constant ,. direction_vector)  0  NB. fork 
+---+---+----+-----+
|1 2|1 2|1   |0 0  |
+---+---+----+-----+
|1 2|3 4|0.5 |_2 _2|
+---+---+----+-----+
|1 2|0 5|1   |1 _3 |
+---+---+----+-----+
|1 2|2 1|0.25|_1 1 |
+---+---+----+-----+
```